# Keyword highlighting on selection in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

A little while ago I managed to get Visual Studio 2008 (C++) into a state where, if I would select a keyword (or any symbol for that matter), by either double clicking on it or highlighting it, all other instances of that symbol within the current file would become highlighted too.

This was a really useful feature.

Since then it's gone away, and I don't know how to get it back.

Please help.

@Sander - that'll be it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you've installed [RockScroll](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingRockScroll.aspx). It also lights them up in the graphical scrollbar (its main feature)

Answer (score 1):

I use [MetalScroll](http://code.google.com/p/metalscroll/), it's like RockScroll only better; it doesn't interfere with Resharper (a VS must-have) and you can set it up to only highlight if you hold down 'alt' when you double-click.

Answer (score 0):

There is something called "**WordLight**" by Mikhail Nasyrov.
An add-in for Visual Studio 2008 that highlights all occurrences of a selected text.
It searches and highlights substrings that are currently selected in a text editor.
Can be found at below link
[WordLight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MikhailNasyrov.WordLight)

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MikhailNasyrov.WordLight