# Highlight similar strings in Visual Studio like in Notepad++, for any file type

Tags: visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

Some people have mentioned [RockScroll](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingRockScroll.aspx) and [MetaScroll](http://code.google.com/p/metalscroll/) in [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132452/keyword-highlighting-on-selection-in-visual-studio-2008), but those only seem to work in code, is there something that will work with ***any*** file type, including plain text files?

In Resharper I can do ALT-SHIFT-F11, but again, that only works in source files, I need this functionality in plain text files as well.  If not then at least in JavaScript and HTML files.

Screen shot below is of Notepad++ in action.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [WordLight](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ad686131-47d4-4c13-ada2-5b1a9019fb6f) add-in for VS2008, it highlights substrings that are currently selected in a text editor.